# loop/recur is producing infinite abrupt results while the answer is correct for 1st value of collection

Tags: clojure

I have a list of values and I am performing some calculation on the first value of list and storing the result in a data structure.

I am new to clojure and I think problem lies in running the loops

```
(defn cal-funct [mean-value ,st-dev ,values]

 (def pi 3.14159)
(def e 2.71828)

(loop [f [] 
      values values
     ]
(if (not-empty values)
(do
(println str "first " (first values))
(let [y (* (/ 1 (* st-dev (Math/sqrt (* 2 pi)))) (Math/pow e (* -1 (/ (Math/pow (- (first values) mean-value) 2) (* 2 (Math/pow st-dev 2))))))
]
(println str "y is" y)
(recur (rest values) (conj f y))
)
)

f
)
)
 )
```

y should be calculated for all values of #values while its running infinite..

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as "answered", please!

Answer (score 3):

You have your arguments to `recur` the wrong way round. You're binding `(rest values)` to `f` and `(conj f y)` to `values` in the `recur` call, so `values` will never be empty.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code.  The first is that it is not formatted at all.  Clojure has a fairly universally accepted style guide with only few variations, e. g. documented [here](https://guide.clojure.style/).  Not formatting code leads to incredibly hard to see, but in essence very simple, bugs.

Here is your code, formatted:

```
(defn cal-funct [mean-value ,st-dev ,values]
  (def pi 3.14159)
  (def e 2.71828)
  (loop [f [] 
         values values]
    (if (not-empty values)
      (do
        (println str "first " (first values))
        (let [y (* (/ 1
                      (* st-dev
                         (Math/sqrt (* 2 pi))))
                   (Math/pow e
                             (* -1
                                (/ (Math/pow (- (first values) mean-value)
                                             2)
                                   (* 2 (Math/pow st-dev 2))))))]
          (println str "y is" y)
          (recur (rest values)
                 (conj f y))))
      f)))
```

In no particular order:

- Don't use `def` in a function body, use `let` instead.  In this case, it seems that you want `pi` and `e` to be global constants, so define them outside.
- Comma `,` is whitespace.  It serves no purpose in a parameter list like that.
- `str` is a function.  I do not think that you want to print it.
- After formatting, you can see that the order of `recur` arguments is not the same as in the `loop` bindings.
- The function name should reflect what is calculated.

Some more improvements:

- `(/ 1 whatever)` can be expressed as `(/ whatever)`.
- `(* -1 whatever)` can be expressed as `(- whatever)`.
- Maybe extract the calculation of `y`.
- This kind of loop-recur is better expressed as a `mapv`.